# Efficiently join multiple CSV files keeping the header from first file in C#

Tags: c#, performance, csv, io

Given multiple CSV files, that can be hundreds of megabytes or more per file. They all have the same header row starting the file and have CRLF at the end of each line. Each file may or may not have a CRLF at the end of the file. The goal is to:

1. Join a list of files.
2. Keep the header from the first file.
3. Output them to a new file.
4. These files may have thousands of columns and millions of rows.
5. The files must be processed in the order given, and order of the rows is significant.

Given the size of the files, this needs to be as fast and memory efficient as possible.

Comment: Do you have to reorder any of the data in order to output to a common column order?

Comment: @Plutonix no. All columns stay in the order they are defined.

Comment: Have a look at csvhelper on nuget. You might not need to re-invent the wheel

Answer (score 3):

If the headers are the same, then you can just open a write stream, then go through all the input files, opening read streams for them and copying data. The first file is copied in its entirety. Subsequent files have the first line skipped.

That approach would be the fastest, so long as you are 100% sure the columns align and it's only the first line that needs skipping.

This kind of thing would be quite straightforward to do on a Unix-style command line, btw.

Comment: "then go through all the input files" -- I suggest using [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) for simplicity and the fact that it won't read the entire file(s) into memory. And it won't have issues where "the last line may not have crlf at the end", it will still read that line. Just have to manually make a counter and skip the first line `if (counter == 1) { continue; }`. The writer should be nested in the reader foreach, again to save memory. Read 1 line, write 1 line, iterate repeat.

Comment: @Quantic, the problem with `File.ReadLines` is that it allocates all of them in memory. It's far more efficient (which is a goal in the original question) to just read a `byte[]` buffer with some large number of elements, and write to the output stream. That can run with minimal or even no garbage collection. You could use [`StreamReader.ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) in a loop, but what if you hit a really big line? The strings are still allocated and collected. It's more efficient to work with a fixed size buffer.

Comment: Ah ok good point about the really big line. I thought File.ReadLines only kept 1 line in memory and that File.ReadAllLines was the one that read the whole thing in? Or is it just that File.ReadLines only grabs one line at a time (as the foreach iterates), but the previous ones are still held in memory?

Comment: You're right about the difference between `ReadLines` and `ReadAllLines`, my mistake. Still, by the time you get to the end of the file, you've allocated each byte on the GC and collected it. If you use a buffer, you only allocate that buffer once and the GC doesn't have any work to do during reading/writing. Also, for binary data (I know the question is about CSV, but still) you risk corrupting the file due to the multiple ways you can interpret line endings.